# Delete button not working.. Error: Object not found

Tags: php, html

I am making an ecommerce website. So far, all are okay except where I want to delete items in the cart based on my cart database. The cart comprises of cart_id and menu_id.

Whenever I click the button (Delete), there is an error shown
**"Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.2 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1"**

I can't figure out what was my mistake. Hope you can help me. Thanks

```
  <div class="container-2">

<?php
include('cart.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['delete_submit'])) {
    // call method addToCart
    $Cart->deleteCart($_POST['menu_id']);
  }
}

?>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col h2 ">
    <img src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Starbucks-Emblem.png" class="Logo" alt="Logo" />
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row" style="min-height: 20vh; border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;">

  <div class="col" style="text-align: left;">

    <!-- Display Item From Database -->
    <h3>Order here</h3>


    <div class="row" style="padding: 1rem; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">
      <?php
      foreach ($menu->getData('cart') as $item) :
        $cart = $menu->getProduct($item['menu_id']);
        $subTotal[] = array_map(function ($item) {

      ?>

          <div class="col">


            <div>
              <img src="<?php echo $item['menu_image'] ?? "./menu-img/Warm Drinks/Brewed Coffee/Caffe ministo.jpeg"; ?>" style="width: 80%; border-radius: 25px;">
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0.5rem;">
              <h3>₱ <?php echo $item['menu_price'] ?? "0.00"; ?></h3>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col" style="margin: auto;">
            <h5><?php echo $item['menu_name'] ?? "Unknown"; ?></h6><br>


          </div>

          <div class="col text-center" style="padding-top: 8%;">
            <form action="post">
              <input value="<?php echo $item['menu_id'] ?? 0; ?>" name="menu_id">
              <?php
              echo '<button type="submit" name="delete_submit" class="btn-default btn-lg"><p >Delete</p></button>';
              ?>

            </form>
          </div>

          <!-- !cart item -->
      <?php
          return $item['menu_price'];
        }, $cart);

      endforeach;

      ?>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

function:

```
    public function deleteCart($menu_id = null, $table = "cart")
{
    if ($menu_id != null) {
        $result = $this->db->con->query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE menu_id={$menu_id}");
        if ($result) {
            header("Location:" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the [Form Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)'s `action` attribute to `post`. This attribute actually specifies the URL that the post data should be sent to. So instead of POSTing to the current URL, it's trying to send the data as a GET request (the default method) to `http://yourdomain/post`. What you need to do is set the `method` attribute instead and omit the `action` attribute.

```
<form method="post">
  <button> Delete </button>
</form>
```